# Can't convert R date ordinal to Python accurately

Tags: python, r, datetime, rpy2

Following on from the question here:

I'm trying to create the series by hand here using Rpy2

```
import rpy2.robjects as ro
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
import pandas.rpy.common as com

pa = importr("pa")

ro.r("data(jan)")
jan = com.load_data('jan')

jan_r  = com.convert_to_r_dataframe(jan)

name = ro.StrVector([str(i) for i in jan['name']])
sector = ro.StrVector([str(i) for i in jan['sector']])
date = ro.StrVector([str(i) for i in jan['date']])
```

and I get at date number of `14610` in the date field representing `2010-01-01` which I suspect is a `1970-01-01` origin. I can't find anything in the `datetime` module that will allow me to change the origin for the date however so I don't know how to reset it.

My questions:

1. Is the origin for the R sourced date `1970-01-01`?
2. Is there a way to set an origin and covert to a `datetime.datetime` object in python?
3. Am I missing something more obvious here?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is the origin for the R sourced date `1970-01-01`?

From [`?Date`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/Date):

> Dates are represented as the number of days since 1970-01-01, with negative values for earlier dates.

---

> I get at date number of 14610 in the date field representing 2010-01-01 which I suspect is a 1970-01-01 origin.

Well suspected.

```
as.Date(14610, origin = "1970-01-01")
## [1] "2010-01-01"
```

---

> Is there a way to set an origin and covert to a datetime.datetime object in python?

Python [datetime docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date) show several ways of constructing a date.

You can use `datetime.date(year, month, day)` syntax, where those values can be retrieved from the R dates using `year(x)`, `month(x)` and `mday(x)`, where `x` represents your date vector.

You can use `date.fromtimestamp(timestamp)` syntax, where the timestamps can be retrieved from the R dates using `format(x)`.

The `date.fromordinal(ordinal)` documentation returns:

> the date corresponding to the  Gregorian ordinal, where January 1 of year 1 has ordinal 1

So presumably your problem is that you are passing dates as numbers which R calculates as days from 1st Jan 1970, and python assumes are from 1st Jan 0001.

Comment: thanks @RichieCotton. In this case I don't get to choose the input format of the data. I think I'll just add the timedelta to the numbers in this instance. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, but how to express this number correctly in python?

```python
import datetime
pd.to_datetime(18402,unit='D', origin='1970-1-1')`
```

18402 corresponds to 2020-05-20. The parameter *origin* is the default one, so you can skip it.